# How to Extract Rows of Data into a DataFrame using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to extract the rows from a webpage into a dataframe.

I get an error because I do not understand how to put the code for the first element and the last element in the `find_element` partю

I do understand this [exists](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements), but I still do not get it how to actually extract the table from the link.

I am using Сhrome, so I do right-click and inspect. But I do not know where to take it from there to actually get the right code to put it in the `find_element` to extract the rows of results.

What am I trying to do? I am trying to extract the rows in the search result and put it in a dataframe/table in Python.

What do I put in these parts to be able to extract all the columns and rows of the link:

```
elem = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("")
post_elems = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("")
```

---

The output will be the following table with its data:

```
Products Released | Lifecycle  Start Date | Mainstream Support End Date |Extended Support End Date  |Service Pack Support End Date  | Notes
```

Comment: What do you want to do actually?

Comment: @RatmirAsanov I want to extract the results of the search result as a table

Comment: @Victor share desired output as it's not quite clear which exact data you want to extract

Comment: @Andersson I want to extract the results of the link as a dataframe, I also updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code for that:

```
results_table = []
rows = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("tr.ng-scope")

for row in rows:

    temp = []
    columns = row.find_elements_by_css_selector("td")

    for column in columns:

        temp.append(column.text)

    results_table.append(temp)
```

To get the headers you can use:

```
headers = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("th")
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Two questions, 1) How did you __tr.ng-scope__ 2) Where did you define __results_table__ ?

Comment: 1) I have used Developer Tools in Chrome (Inspect elements); 2) Updated answer.

Comment: this worked great ! Thank you. Can you also use the same method to extract tables from different links on the same page ?

Comment: What do you mean by "from different links on the same page"?

Comment: I created a new question :)